# i am getting Error while checking string value in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am checking two values inside list using if condition and another string should not be in list in python below is my code but it is giving wrong output

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] #list values or lis =[]
if ('z' or 'a') and not 'x' in lis :
    print "yes"
else :
    print "no"
```

and output is

```
yes
```

is there anything wrong?

Comment: Is this a question or an opinion? Either way, your `if` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: question how to achieve this requirement i now in java but in python!!!

Comment: Output of above code will be `yes` as the  `if` condition is `True`.  
 [Among 'z' or 'a', the list has 'a'. and the list does not have any 'x'.]

Comment: @DanielRoseman : There is an 'and' clause between the two conditions. I agree that first condition is always `True` and second condition is based on the elements of `lis`. Combining both conditions (with give data in second condition) will yield the result as 'yes' .

Comment: @KeyurPotdar : correct and to the point.

Comment: lis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
if ('z' in lis or 'a' in lis) and not 'y' in lis : 
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')  it will meet your requirment enjoyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('z' or 'a')` evaluates to be a truthy value (`'z'`) and hence you get `yes` as output.

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] #list values or lis =[]
if 'z' in lis or 'a' in lis and not 'x' in lis :
    print "yes"
else :
    print "no"
```

Comment: if ('z' in lis or 'a' in lis) and not 'x' in lis :  this output giving is correct

Comment: what is truthy value???

Comment: @ParaM, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false

Comment: @ParaM, thx for your brackets help

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `if` statement evaluates like this:

- `('z' or 'a')` -> `'z'` (which is *truthy*)
- `not 'x' in lis` - > `True`

So, it becomes `if 'z' and True`, which is `True`.

Use this code instead:

```
lis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
if any(item in lis for item in ('z', 'a')) and 'x' not in lis:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

This will check if any of the items in the tuple `('z', 'a')` are in the list, and whether `'x'` isn't.

Comment: if lis = [ ] still output is "yes"  any way @keyuor diamond

Answer (score -1):

In the first condition, you're making a generic statement that is considered true. If you want to see if `z` or `a` is in `lis`, it should look like this:

```
lis = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] #list values
if ('z' or 'a') in lis and not 'x' in lis :
    print "yes"
 else :
     print "no"
```

Comment: if ('z' or 'a') in lis and not 'x' in lis :
output is "no"  it wrong output please check in

Comment: The question was edited after I answered. You originally had if ('z' or 'z') which made me think you were looking for "no" but were getting "yes", that's what I was answering for...

Comment: @para m answer is correct out put even list is empty